# How can integrate gulpjs in CakePhp 2.x ?

Tags: php, cakephp, gulp, gulp-sass

I want to integrate gulpjs into Php Framework (CakePhp 2.x), what would be best practice to use gulp to achieve following feature in CakePhp:

- Minification of CSS, JavaScript, and images.
- Automatically reload the browser after change.
- Sass Compilation

  Note: I am new in gulpjs, please suggest use cases of gulpjs in Cakephp 2.x.

Comment: This article I wrote might help you get started http://andy-carter.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-to-the-task-runner-gulp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install `Nodejs` https://nodejs.org/en/download/.

install `Npm` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.

install gulp globally. `npm install --global gulp-cli`

create a package.json file in your root directory.

navigate to your project directory from terminal : `npm install --save-dev gulp-install`

Create a gulpfile.js at the root of your project.

`var gulp = require('gulp');
 gulp.task('default', function() 
 {// place code for your default task here
 });`

Run gulp from terminal `gulp`

Now you have gulp installation in your project.
you can refer here https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass for saas and gulp task.

Similarly you can find minify and other plugins from http://gulpjs.com/plugins/.

There is good [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wNlEK8qrb0M) tutorial to get you started.

Comment: So Nodejs must be installed on server to run gulpjs in Php based application ?

Comment: `node Js` has nothing to do with your `PHP` application and there is no need to install it on your production server. `npm` will manage dependencies for gulp and its packages that's why you need to install node on your development machine.

Comment: Indeed, nodejs has nothing to do with cakephp or php in general

Answer (score 0):

There is a Node module that helps you do that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cakephp-elixir

From the documentation:

> If you love Elixir, but also love CakePHP, you wil love Elixir for
>   CakePHP!
>
> Elixir for CakePHP provides a clean, fluent API for defining basic
>   Gulp tasks for your CakePHP application. Elixir supports common CSS
>   and JavaScript pre-processors like Sass and Webpack. Using method
>   chaining, Elixir allows you to fluently define your asset pipeline.
>   For example:
>
> ```
> elixir(function(mix) {
>     mix.sass('default.scss')
>        .webpack('default.js');
> });
> ```
>
> If you've ever been confused and overwhelmed about getting started
>   with Gulp and asset compilation, you will love Elixir for CakePHP.
>   However, you are not required to use it while developing your
>   application. You are free to use any asset pipeline tool you wish, or
>   even none at all.